# Still can get friend list from facebook api?

Tags: facebook, api

I want to get friend list from facebook by using facebook api. Is it working or not. Can you help me by giving accurate information ?

Comment: http://techcrunch.com/2015/04/28/facebook-api-shut-down/#.nndwtm:nael more information

Answer (score 1):

You are only able to get the friends list who are using your facebook application.